# I have made a Java programme but has repetition problem

Tags: java

I have created that Java programme but it have repetition problem, I want that if one question has done either right or wrong it must not be ask again.
It should ask 10 question only. I have tried alot to change but every time I am getting error.

***I have created that Java programme but it have repetition problem, I want that if one question has done either right or wrong it must not be ask again.
It should ask 10 question only. I have tried alot to change but every time I am getting error.***

```js
package examapp;

import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Examapp {

    
    static int nQuestions = 0; static int nCorrect = 0;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
           
              int prevNum=0;
              int sum=0;
              do{
                  Random rand = new Random();
              int randomNum = rand.nextInt((11 - 1) + 1) + 1;
                  if(randomNum==prevNum){
                      prevNum=randomNum;
                     
                  }
                else if(randomNum==1){
                 String question1;
        question1 = "What was the name of Google in late 90s?\n";
        question1+="A. Googol\n";
        question1+="B. Gigablast\n";
        question1+="C. Backrub\n";
        question1+="D. Google\n";
                question1+="Marks=9";
        check(question1,"C");
                sum=sum+1;
                      
                  }
                  
                else if(randomNum==2){
                      String question2;
        question2 = "\"Do no evil\" is a tagline of?\n";
        question2+="A. Yahoo\n";
        question2+="B. Google\n";
        question2+="C. Bing\n";
        question2+="D. Duck Duck Go\n";
                question2+="Marks=9";
        check(question2,"B");
                sum=sum+1;
                  }
                
                  else if(randomNum==3){
                      String question3;
        question3 = "Which of the following is fully Object Oriented Programming Language?\n";
        question3+="A. SmallTalk\n";
        question3+="B. Kotlin\n";
        question3+="C. Java\n";
        question3+="D. F#\n";
                question3+="Marks=9";
        check(question3,"A");
                
                sum=sum+1;
                      
                  }
                  
                  else if(randomNum==4){
                      String question4;
        question4 = "Which among the following is not a mobile Operating System?\n";
        question4+="A. Bada\n";
        question4+="B. Safari\n";
        question4+="C. WebOS\n";
        question4+="D. MeeGo\n";
                question4+="Marks=9";
        check(question4,"B");
                sum=sum+1;
                 
                
                  }
                  else if(randomNum==5){
                      String question5;
        question5 = "Which of the following is a correct format of Email address?\n";
        question5+="A. info.website.com\n";
        question5+="B. info@website.com\n";
        question5+="C. info@website@com\n";
        question5+="D. info.website@com\n";
                question5+="Marks=9";
                
        check(question5,"B");
                sum=sum+1;
                  }
                  
                else  if(randomNum==6){
                 String question6;
        question6 = "What is the shortcut key of printing a document for computer having windows?\n";
        question6+="A. Ctrl + Shift + P\n";
        question6+="B. Alt + P\n";
        question6+="C. Ctrl + Alt + P\n";
        question6+="D. Ctrl + P\n";
                question6+="Marks=9";
        check(question6,"D");
                sum=sum+1;
                  }
                  
              else if(randomNum==7){
                String question7;
        question7 = "Computer software includes\n";
        question7+="A. Packaged programs\n";
        question7+="B. Operating system programs\n";
        question7+="C. Applications programs\n";
        question7+="D. All of these\n";
                question7+="Marks=9";
        check(question7,"D");
                     
                 }
                  
            else if(randomNum==8){
                     String question8;
        question8 = "A function inside another function is called a _______ function\n";
        question8+="A. Nested\n";
        question8+="B. Round\n";
        question8+="C. Sum\n";
        question8+="D. Grouped\n";
                question8+="Marks=9";
        check(question8,"A");
                
                sum=sum+1;
                 
                 }
                  
                else if(randomNum==9){
                     String question9;
        question9 = "What does HTTP stands for?\n";
        question9+="A. Hypertext Transfer Plotter\n";
        question9+="B. Hypertext Transfer Plot\n";
        question9+="C. Hypertext Transfer Protocol\n";
        question9+="D. Head Tail Transfer Protocol\n";
                question9+="Marks=9";
        check(question9,"C");
                sum=sum+1;
                   
                 }
              else  if(randomNum==10){
                     String question10;
        question10 = "The term 'Pentium' is realted to\n";
        question10+="A. DVD\n";
        question10+="B. Hard Disk\n";
        question10+="C. Microprocessor\n";
        question10+="D. Mouse\n";
                question10+="Marks=9";
        check(question10,"C");
                sum=sum+1;
                 }
                  
              else{
                  prevNum=randomNum;
              
              }
                
                
                
             
                  
              }while(sum<=9);

        
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,nCorrect + " correct out of 10" + " questions");
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Total Obtained Marks="+(nCorrect*9));
    }
    

    public static String ask(String question) {

        
        while(true) {
            
            String answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(question);
            answer = answer.toUpperCase();
            
            if(!(answer.equals("A") || answer.equals("B") || answer.equals("C") || answer.equals("D"))){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid Answer");
                continue;
            }
            
        return answer; 
        }
    }

    static void check(String question, String correctAnswer) {
        nQuestions++;
        String answer = ask(question);

        if(answer.equals(correctAnswer)) {
            
            nCorrect++;
        }
        else {
            
        }
    }
    
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your main is quite cluttered. By the time you get to the bottom, you have already forgotten what was on top, such as that it is a very large do-while block. If I were you, I would put the questions and answers in an array, list or even better in your own question object. Then you could use array shuffle to put them in different order for each run and omit all the if-else blocks. It is best to also pull your initialization from random out of the loop so that you don't create a new object with every iteration.

In order to answer your question, so that you do not use an already generated random number again, you must somehow remember the already generated ones. For example, use a list.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    int count = 0;
    int randomNum;
    do{
        randomNum = rand.nextInt(10)+1;
        while(list.contains(randomNum)){
            randomNum = rand.nextInt(10)+1;
        }
        list.add(randomNum);
        count++;
        
        // rest of your code goes here
    }while( count < 10);
    System.out.println(list);
}
```